# Как заставить контейнер следить за движением сайдбара в css

Tags: html, css

У меня на сайте есть сайдбар и блок div. Выглядит это всё вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я нажимаю кнопку закрытия сайдбара (крестик рядом с логотипом), он уезжает влево, за экран и страница выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу добиться того, чтобы контейнер UserTable при закрытие сайдбара уезжал влево на столько же пикселей, на сколько уезжает сайдбар, т.е. закрепить его за сайдбаром. Следовательно, когда сайдбар открывается, контейнер смещается в право, а когда закрывается - влево. Как это можно реализовать? Сразу скажу что у сайдбара стоит position absolute и если это свойство изменить на relative например, то тогда контейнер уезжает в самый низ и его вообще не видно на странице. Есть ли способ закрепить контейнер за сайдбаром?

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать 2 колонки и менять их ширину. Через `display: flex` или `display: grid`. [Ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: Можно так, да только сайт на реакте и уже свёрстан таким образом, поэтому менять display в этом случае тоже не вариант

Comment: Тогда костыльное решение - зная ширину левого блока, добавляйте/убирайте его ширину к правому блоку, либо сам элемент сдвигайте на его ширину. Возможно через js, но без более подробного описания проблемы и без примера Вашего кода будет ответить проблематично

Comment: Как сказал Pashok только через JS. Узнаёте ширину бокового меню, и сужаете или расширяете ваш UserTable на эту величину.